# How to serve user specific static content in Express.js

Tags: node.js, security, express, assets, static-content

I want to serve **user-specific static content** in Express. That means, if a user is logged in, his private static folder is served by express. Other users shall not have access.

I tried the following (see below), but the static content is not being served. In fact, the route seems to be completely ignored and I get a 404.

I am not sure if the way I do it is the right way to go and if express is capable of dynamically serving different static folders. Thanks in advance for your thoughts on this.

**Here's the code (simplified):**

routes.js:

```
express = require 'express'
router = express.Router()

router.use '/user/assets', (req, res, next) ->
    if req.user
        userpath = 'uploads/' + md5(req.user._id)
        if not fs.existsSync userpath
            fs.mkdirSync userpath
            console.log "Created user directory at " + userpath

        express.static(userpath)
    next()

module.exports = router
```

index.js:

```
express = require 'express'
app = express()
app.use '/', require './routes'
```

**Sidenotes**:

The md5 is just a way of escaping weird characters in the user id, which is a string. I know there is a possibility for a mismatch, which is tiny, and about which I don't wanna care for now. Concerns about general security of the fashion of the solving attempt are appreciated.
The code is written in CoffeeScript.

`req.user` contains a valid user element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calling `express.static` is not enough, you need to `use()` it with the router. Unfortunately you can't directly do that, since you require a different set of routes for each user.

Calling `express.static` will return a middleware function. You could call it directly, i.e. something like this:

```
var files = express.static(userpath);
return files(req, res, next);
```

However that's still not enough, as the middleware uses `req.url` to build the file path. The express router adjusts this property and removes the mount point (see [`req.originalUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) in the docs). So you need to strip `/user/assets` from it, before calling the middleware.

By the way, you should set the `DEBUG` environment variable for node. It allows you to see what routes are created by express, which is very handy in debugging `express.static` 404 problems. E.g. you'd do `$ DEBUG=* node index.js` on Linux.

As you can see the approach starts to be a bit hacky and creating a new `express.static` middleware on each request is not very performance friendly too. So depending on what your user directories contain, using [`res.sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) might actually be better.

As a sidenote, I assume you've checked that `req.user` actually contains something if the user is logged in.

Comment: Great, thanks! res.sendFile was exactly what I was looking for. Otherwise it would indeed end up to be hacky.